# mixing multiple charset in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8, character-encoding

I would like to store in my database both `utf8` and `utf8mb4` charset. 
For now all my database has a unique charset `utf8` and a unique collation `utf8_unicode_ci` but I need to store some data in `utf8mb4`.

I think it is possible to mix both charset, `utf8` is a subset of `utf8mb4` so they are compatible. But I would like to know how to configure my database to be the more efficient :

- which charset to use for the client ?
- which charset to use for the connection ?
- which charset to use for the results ?
- Is it possible to mix charset without performance issue ? I will not compare `utf8` and `utf8mb4` columns

Thank you

Comment: Why not convert it all to utf8mb4?

Comment: That's a solution indeed, I'm trying to do that but I have new issues with innodb configuration. Even if I choose this solution, I think it can be helpful to have answer to my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have any mixture of `CHARACTER SETs` among the columns in a table.  `SET NAMES` (or some connection parameter) establishes the encoding of the *client's* bytes; use `utf8mb4` there.

Also consider the newer collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

There are no significant performance issues.